# when is domain context created?

Tags: service, dns, ria

Dear all
I am confused about domain context that wether they are counterpart of domain services or the mirror image on the client side?

when are they created ?
means are they created at the same time when we create domain services classes?  or when we build the solution then we can add domain context from client side?

why there is the need for domain context when we already have domain services classes through which client access is permitted?

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer myself while studying several tutorials

what happens when we create a domain service for a particular entity on the server side the as  soon as we check the option of enable client access simultaneously client proxies are developed on the client side offcourse.

there is the generation of the classes on the client side and we can access those entities through those classes or what we call proxies.

domain context provides easy access to the functionality on the server side.

it contains wcf proxy that makes service calls